# Number Theory Problem, proving Congruency with a condition

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I've been working on a problem for 4 days now and I can't figure out a way to solve it... This problem states :

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$
Prove that if $y\equiv 7x\mod{26}$, then $15y\equiv x\mod{26}$

I proved earlier that
For $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a\equiv b\mod{c}\Longrightarrow ka\equiv kb\mod{c}$

Could someone give me an intuition about where to start to solve this problem ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: You only need that $7\cdot 15\equiv 1\bmod 26$. Therefore $15y\equiv 1\cdot x$. This is very easy, and it follows with $k=15$ in your notation (so you had almost solved it).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I hope my answer is mathematically okay???? Because I felt that approach should get the OP some way of viewing how it he/she can get a slight insight into the theory of modular arithmetic....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $y \equiv 7x \pmod{26} \implies y = 26k + 7x$
Multiply both sides by 15 and you'll get $15y = 26 \times 15 \times k + 105x = 26\times 15 \times k + 26 \times 4 \times x + x = 26(15k + 4x) + x \implies 15y \equiv x \pmod{26}$

It's often good to look into these congruence problems like this so you may get to know where the loophole lies. And let me be frank, this one was rather simple due to this approach.

Comment: Thank you ! This solution is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @PierreSCubing thanks... also it would be worth looking into a comment beneath your question which was left by the one who edited your post. Compare this answer and the comment and look back at how to solve it yourself ;)